# The previously configured ChromeDriver service is still running / Running Webdriver tests with Grunt

Tags: selenium, reactjs, gruntjs, webdriver, mocha.js

Hi I am trying to write mocha tests for my react application that leverage selenium-webdriver.

I have a few questions but help either of them would help so I can move forward.

1. First of all, ideally, I would like to share the same webdriver sessions across my different tests since I do not care about what order they run. I just want to load the webpage once, run all of the tests and then close the webpage. Is this possible? I initially put my before and after cases in a different file outside of a describe and it was working fine...but then I could not access the instance of the driver in any of my test files.
2. If sharing the same session is not possible, then how can I solve the error below which occurs when I try to run two specFiles..

Here is the error:

```
$ grunt test-e2e
Running "mochatest:e2e" (mochatest) task
Running Mocha tests on files
/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/tests/e2e/testSpecOne.js
/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/tests/e2e/testSpecTwo.js

Error: The previously configured ChromeDriver service is still running. You must shut it down before you may adjust its configuration.
    at Error (native)
    at Object.setDefaultService (/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/chrome.js:264:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/tests/e2e/testSpecTwo.js:8:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:556:32)
    at loader (/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/userName/Desktop/myReactApp/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:473:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:432:12)
```

A typical test looks like this:

```
import assert from 'assert';
import test from 'selenium-webdriver/testing';
import webdriver, {By, until} from 'selenium-webdriver';
import chrome from 'selenium-webdriver/chrome';
import chromedriver from 'chromedriver';
import helpers from './helpers.js';

chrome.setDefaultService(new chrome.ServiceBuilder(chromedriver.path).build());


test.describe('Main page', () => {

  let driver = new webdriver
                    .Builder()
                    .withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.chrome())
                    .build();

  test.before(() => {
      helpers.launchTheApp(driver, 'http://localhost:8000/myApp', 'elementOne', 10000);
  });

  test.after(() => {
    helpers.closeTheApp(driver);
  })

  test.it('Test some items appear', () => {

    helpers.checkIfElementIsPresent(driver, By.className, 'elementOne');
    helpers.checkIfElementIsPresent(driver, By.className, 'elementTwo');
    helpers.checkIfElementIsPresent(driver, By.className, 'elementThree');

   });
});
```

I am using a grunt-mocha-test to run these tests configured like this

```
e2e:{
    options: {
        timeout: 3000000,
        ignoreLeaks: true,
        ui: 'bdd',
        run: true,
        log: true,
        reporter: typeof process.env.FUSION_BUILD_GENERATED === 'undefined' ? 'spec' : 'xunit-file',
        grep: grunt.option('grep')
    },
    src: ['tests/e2e/**/**/*Spec.js']
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One possible solution is to run your sessions in isolated environments (for example in [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) containers). However trying to achieve this with standard Selenium is complicated - you have to manually start and stop containers or use an infrastructure automation tool like [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/). Here is where a new Selenium-compatible tool called [Selenoid](http://github.com/aerokube/selenoid/) comes into play. Just request two separate sessions in your test and they will run in parallel inside Docker containers. This gives you a lot of flexibility. My talk about it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TGjpc32my0Y